# Select records that appear a minimum number of times between dates

Tags: mysql, sql

My table columns are as follows:

```
| ID | UserID | AccountName | SortCode (encrypted) | AccountNumber (encrypted) | DateAdded
```

This table holds a history of bank details for users. If a user changes their bank details in our system, a new row is inserted into this table.

I am trying to create a query which will show users that have changed their details between 2 dates, and possibly a certain number of times between those dates. For example, show users who have changed their details between `2016-01-01` and `2016-06-01` at least 2 times.

Selecting between two dates is trivial, but I am struggling to incorporate the "at least # times". Additionally, the first record for each user should not be included in the results as this record is the user adding their bank details for the first time (so is not a change to their bank details).

Comment: Do you have a seperate unique ID column?

Comment: Yes there is an auto-incrementing primary key column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select UserId
from your_table
where DateAdded >= '2016-01-01' 
  and DateAdded <= '2016-06-01'
and ID not in
(
   select min(ID) from your_table group by userId
)
group by UserId
having count(*) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by user first, then select the user

```
SELECT * FROM Table t2
WHERE t2.UserId IN (
    SELECT t1.UserId
    FROM Table t1
    WHERE t1.DateAdded BETWEEN 'start_date' AND 'end_date'
    GROUP BY t1.UserId
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) AND t2.DateAdded BETWEEN 'start_date' AND 'end_date'
```

EDIT (by Gordon):

I think the subquery answers the OP's question:

```
    SELECT t1.UserId
    FROM Table t1
    WHERE t1.DateAdded BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date
    GROUP BY t1.UserId
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Niyoko's answer goes a step further and gets the original detail records.

---

#### Edit

I missed requirement in the last paragraph. To exclude first row for each user from being counted, use following SQL

```
SELECT t1.UserId
FROM Data t1
WHERE t1.DateAdded BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-06'
AND t1.Id <> (SELECT Id FROM Data t2 WHERE t1.UserId = t2.UserId ORDER BY DateAdded LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY t1.UserId
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: @scaisEdge First one, you need for getting user who modified two times at that date, second one is for selecting the details. If you don't want the details, then the inner query is enough.

Comment: What about the last paragraph of the question? *Additionally, the first record for each user should not be included in the results as this record is the user adding their bank details for the first time*

Comment: @juergend I missed that part. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answers provided, I was able to come up with a solution that does not require the ID column to be ordered and seems to be very efficient across quite a large data set. The SQL I ended up using is below. It does create a few temporary tables but seems to be the fastest solution I have found. I will also note that this SQL does not incorporate the "minimum number of occurrences" requirement that I needed. I implemented that requirement in PHP rather than SQL as the SQL would need a large portion duplicated just to fulfil the requirement.

```
SELECT *
FROM UserBankDetails AS bd
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID
    FROM UserBankDetails
    WHERE (UserID, DateAdded) IN (
        SELECT UserID, MIN(DateAdded)
        FROM UserBankDetails
        GROUP BY UserID
    )
) AS temp ON bd.ID = temp.ID
WHERE temp.ID IS NULL
AND bd.DateAdded BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-01'
ORDER BY bd.UserID, bd.DateAdded
```

The difficulty was efficiently excluding the earliest record for each user. This solution creates a temporary table containing the `MIN DateAdded` for each user, and then uses a [`left exclusion join`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) to exclude those records from the final result set.

As stated, I did not incorporate the "minimum number of occurrences" requirement, however, this could be done like so (see how verbose it is):

```
SELECT *
FROM UserBankDetails AS bd
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID
    FROM UserBankDetails
    WHERE (UserID, DateAdded) IN (
        SELECT UserID, MIN(DateAdded)
        FROM UserBankDetails
        GROUP BY UserID
    )
) AS temp ON bd.ID = temp.ID
WHERE temp.ID IS NULL
AND bd.DateAdded BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-01'
AND bd.UserID IN (
    SELECT UserID
    FROM UserBankDetails AS bd1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT ID
        FROM UserBankDetails
        WHERE (UserID, DateAdded) IN (
            SELECT UserID, MIN(DateAdded)
            FROM UserBankDetails
            GROUP BY UserID
        )
    ) AS temp1 ON bd1.ID = temp1.ID
    WHERE temp1.ID IS NULL
    AND bd1.DateAdded BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-01'
    GROUP BY UserID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
ORDER BY bd.UserID, bd.DateAdded
```